# How to populate a list box with jquery/js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm still new to MVC and today I am trying to work with the ListBoxFor control.

I was able to create a list and populate it from my model.

However I'm struggling with several issues

How can I populate a list box client side in MVC?
How would I set up an empty list box?

For example my view looks like this:

```
Cars List Box                  Selected Cars
Honda
Ford                ->
Chevy               <-
BMW
```

The user will select a car and click the button (->) to add it to the selected cars list.
This would also work in vice versa, but right now I'm trying to figure out how to populate the selected cars list.

Right now my code is pretty simple.

```
<div>
    <h4>Cars</h4>
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCars, new MultiSelectList(Model.AvailableCars), new { Size = 10 })
</div>

<div>
    <h4>Selected Cars</h4>
    // Not quite sure how to set this up.
</div>
```

Comment: `$(yourAddButton).click(function() { $(selectedCarsListBox).append($('#SelectedCars option:selected')) });`

Comment: As a side note, this is a poor UI, and you will need to ensure that all the options in the 2nd list box are selected before you submit (a ListBox only posts its selected values). You would be better off creating a checkboxlist

Comment: So you are suggesting using the checked list box for the selected cars only?

Comment: No I mean generate a view listing all cars but with a checkbox adjacent each one (checking the checkbox means its selected)

Comment: If you did want the ListBoxes, refer [this fidddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wujr7L4m/) to get you started.

Comment: After playing around today, I'm not sure how checkboxes are better then a listbox.  In my case I need to remove/add the checkboxes from column 1 to column 2.  This hasn't proved to be an easy task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set up a listBox then add this code:

```
$("#YourListID").Append(yourValueToAddHere);
```

The value can be an html if needed as well.